# How to fit my website now

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I have a web application designed and now I am asked to make it fit into different screen resolutions. The front/index page must stay fit into the browsers when maximized, no scrollbar is allowed. Is this feasible or just an odd requirement ? I guess I need to create an image of my website instead then scale it in acccordance with teh browser and the computer screen sizes. 
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: It's feasible to resize your content, but it's hard to tell what you need. Perhaps a sample would help.

Answer (score 9):

To make your web fit into different resolution and devices you will need to use a fluid or responsive layout. One of many links you can find doing a search non the subject: http://webdesignerwall.com/trends/inspiration-fluid-responsive-design

It's usually better to start with a grid (such as http://960.gs/), but you can also adapt the page you already have using [@media-queries](http://mobile.smashingmagazine.com/2010/07/19/how-to-use-css3-media-queries-to-create-a-mobile-version-of-your-website/).

Answer (score -1):

I think Jquery is what you need now: for a scalable screen.

Additional, there is a simple way, try this: 
http://blog.rajatpandit.com/2008/06/19/making-footer-stick-to-the-bottom-of-the-page/

Instead of stick the footer to the bottom, try to stick all things inclding header and container.

Hope it helps.